# Is there a relatively quick way to obtain the scale factor on the metric as a response to special conformal transformation on spacetime?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, conformal-field-theory, scaling

For a special conformal transformation on spacetime positions $$x'^\mu=\frac{x^\mu-x^2b^\mu}{1-2b\cdot x+b^2x^2}$$
I was able to derive the scale factor $$\eta'_{\mu\nu}=\Omega(x)\eta_{\mu\nu}$$by using the transformation property of the metric
$$\eta'_{\mu\nu}=\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial x'^\nu}\eta_{\alpha\beta}$$after a very long algebraic manipulation. But just like how we can build the finite special conformal transformation from infinitesimal version $$\delta x^\mu=2b\cdot x~x^\mu-x^2~b^\mu$$
There should be a way to build the finite transformation of the metric from its infinitesimal version
$$\delta\eta_{\mu\nu}=-\partial_\mu\delta x_\nu - \partial_\nu\delta x_\mu$$
I was not able to do it in this case because for the infinitesimal change in $x$ we can show that $$\delta\left(\frac{x'^\mu}{x^2}\right)=-b^\mu$$ which readily enables me to write down the finite version of it, whereas for $\delta\eta_{\mu\nu}$ I cannot find such a simplification. What should I do to build up the finite change in the metric tensor in this case?